# Use a online database for my localhost wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, configuration, phpmyadmin, config

I have to work with a friend in a wordpress project, and we want to be able to work everyone from our side in localhost.
For this we are using git to have the same code, but we need to use the same database.
I created one database online :

https://xxxx.xxxxxx.com/phpmyadmin

I edit my wp-conf file to have something like this :

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'db_name' );

define( 'DB_USER', 'admin' );

define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '******' );

define( 'DB_HOST', 'https://xxxx.xxxxxx.com' );
```

I already tried with :

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'xxxx.xxxxxx.com/phpmyadmin' );
```

or

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'http://xxxx.xxxxxx.com' );
```

or

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'http://xxxx.xxxxxx.com/phpmyadmin' );
```

etc...

Thanks,

Benjamin.

Comment: Check the connection details with your hosting provider. They'll tell you which host you need to use when connecting to the database externally.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the codex here https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php for setting up your `DB_HOST`

The format should be

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'the_ip_of_the_server' );
```

or in some instances if you need to set a port.

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3307' );

If your host uses Unix sockets or pipes, adjust the DB_HOST value in the wp-config.php file accordingly.

define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' );
// or define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' );
// or define( 'DB_HOST', 'example.tld:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' );
```

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this : I just make the database public.